# Use NSArrays/NSMutableArrays and save in coreData or CorData only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm learing CoreData. I have a simple program that loads a file to a `NSMutableArray`, insert items in an `NSMutableArray`, shows data, and when we close the app saves to file.
I want to change my app to use coreData. 
I think there are two way to do this:

1. Continue using the `NSMutableArray` and use the CoreData to load and save items.
2. Forget the `NSArray` and work only with CoreData

What's the best way? Only coreData or use `NSArrays` and then save to CoreData? What's the best practice for this app in particular and future apps?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't really "just use CoreData". Core Data is a framework for persisting data in iOS. If you want to display that data you still need to pull it out of Core Data and put it into something that can be displayed like an NSArray. You might be better looking at something like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started which is an excellent introduction to Core Data and will answer this question.

Comment: I think core data has a lot of overheads - NSArray's are ram-based but cd is more often disk based so you'll lose speed with cd. However it's much more flexible when collecting and organising data. I think storing an array in a plist will only work up to a certain memory size(...?) so you might not have much choice. But you could serialise the array and use standard NSFileManager stuff to save the raw data to disk. Personally I'd use cd for any more than even a paltry 10 records and I reckon is definitely more future proof.

Comment: @Todd - In general terms, nothing is future proof, ever; nor is anything more necessarily "more" future proof. It all depends on your problem, your contraints, what changes etc.

Comment: Example: if you have a large amount of records and you want to just change a bool flag on a large proportion of them and nothing more. Core Data can be found wanting in this kind of case, as it has to load everything into memory to just change that one flag before paging out again. Compare to SQLite which can flip the flag 'on disk' as it were. I've seen a case study of someone who abandoned Core Data for SQLite due to this example case (their app had horrible performance in CD).

Comment: Also, "CD is more often disk based" - what does that mean exactly? CD is often used to persist data to disk. But to do anything with the data, it must be paged into RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Core Data only to persist your data to disk. However, you would be giving up a lot of convenience that comes with e.g. the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Especially when you have lots of data, the full array of your objects in memory might soon be too much for a device to handle. Core Data includes a great set of tested and mature technologies that help you to keep the integrity of the object graph, manage memory and performance with minimal effort from your part.